# Native crash (SIGSEGV) on android 5.0 with xamarin + mvvmcross

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Xamarin application with Mvvmcross stably crashes on Samsung galaxy s5 with SIGSEGV code probably on MvxImageView with MvxDownloadCache.

Stacktrace:

```
I/DEBUG(282): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x5c
I/DEBUG(282):     r0 00000000  r1 bee36140  r2 9802ec40  r3 bee36140
I/DEBUG(282):     r4 bee360cc  r5 9802ec40  r6 98401c00  r7 98036200
I/DEBUG(282):     r8 12c65fa0  r9 b4e07800  sl 7209a638  fp 000000c0
I/DEBUG(282):     ip b6ddafd7  sp bee360a0  lr b6deef7d  pc b6deecc0  cpsr a0030030
I/DEBUG(282): backtrace:
I/DEBUG(282):     #00 pc 00090cc0  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (AndroidPixelRef::getStorageObj()+11)
I/DEBUG(282):     #01 pc 00090f79  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (JavaHeapBitmapRef::JavaHeapBitmapRef(_JNIEnv*, SkBitmap*, _jbyteArray*)+24)
I/DEBUG(282):     #02 pc 0007cfeb  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG(282):     #03 pc 00b114bd  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat
```

**Upd:** It's full logcat error mesage.

Anybody know what this error mean?

Comment: it's too generic crash description. Did you check Android Device Monitor for additional crash information?

Comment: I know that sigsegv is generic, but i can't find any crash on stackowerflow,google with AndroidPixelRef::getStorageObj and JavaHeapBitmapRef::JavaHeapBitmapRef function calls in stacktrace.

Comment: Is this in release mode? Can you post an issue at https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues so we can look into this? Try to reproduce this with a full error log.

Comment: @martijn Yes in release mode. I have created [issue](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1036) with 3 full crash logs.

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to include your app into the source of MvvmCross, and then run it from there? You then should be able to debug where exactly it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrade MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.DownloadCache library from 3.5.1 to 3.5.0 solve the problem

Comment: It sure did fix my problem, thanks MVVMCROSS for the wasted 8h of debugging trying everything else to fix this issue. Thank god I stumbled upon this.